# Check if the variable is a SVG.js element instance

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I'm using the [svg.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.js) library.

How can we check if a variable `x` is an instance of `SVG` class?

---

I tried:

```
new SVG(document.createDocumentFragment()) instanceof SVG     // false
new SVG(document.createDocumentFragment()).contructor === SVG // false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking what value `SVG` function returns we find that a new `element` is created and returned. It is an instance of `SVG.Doc`:

```
> SVG
svg.js:12 function (element) {
    if (SVG.supported) {
      element = new SVG.Doc(element)

      if (!SVG.parser)
        SVG.prepare(element)

      return element
    }
  }
```

So, the solution is:

```
new SVG(document.createDocumentFragment()) instanceof SVG.Doc // true

// or using the x variable
var x = new SVG(document.createDocumentFragment());
x instanceof SVG.Doc // true
```

Comment: All svg.js elements are ultimately extending the `SVG.Element` class so you can also use that in the instanceof check